# Moti avoid speeding up and down for loop

Tags: react-native, animation, expo, moti

Trying to make a spinner with Moti but having some issue with the speeding down (just want it to spin for ever (I do like that it starts out slow, but not needed).

[image]

```js
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { MotiText } from 'moti'
import React from 'react'
import type { TextStyle } from 'react-native'

import { Colors } from '~/constants/Theme'

type Props = {
  color?: TextStyle['color']
  size?: number
}

export function LoadingSpinner({ color = Colors['white'], size = 15 }: Props) {
  return (
    <MotiText
      from={{
        rotate: '0deg',
      }}
      animate={{
        rotate: '360deg',
      }}
      transition={{
        loop: true,
        repeatReverse: false,
        type: 'timing',
        duration: 5000,
      }}
    >
      <Feather
        name="loader"
        size={size}
        style={{
          paddingBottom: 5,
          color,
        }}
      />
    </MotiText>
  )
}
```

I'm guessing that it's `type: 'timing',` that's the issue, but it seems like I can only do `timing` and `spring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `easing: Easing.linear` to `transition`, where `Easing` is imported from `react-native-reanimated`?

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you Fernando

Comment: happy to hear it!

Comment: You can also change from: 0deg, animate: 359deg (instead of 360deg)

Comment: I don't think that would address the issue.